# Order a pre-defined string array in order

Tags: ios, objective-c, nspredicate

In the following `reversedArray` has **three** or **more** strings such as `Salads`, `Meats` `Appetizer` in order.

However, I want to have `Meats` always to be the **first** string in the array.

```
NSPredicate *predicateMain = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:
                              @"(%K == %@)", @"categoryType", @"main"];

NSPredicate *predicateSide = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:
                              @"(%K == %@)", @"categoryType", @"side"];

NSPredicate *orPredicate = [NSCompoundPredicate orPredicateWithSubpredicates:
                            [NSArray arrayWithObjects:predicateMain, predicateSide,nil]];

NSArray *filteredArray = [foods filteredArrayUsingPredicate:orPredicate];

NSArray *reversedArray = [[[filteredArray valueForKeyPath:
                         @"@distinctUnionOfObjects.categoryName"] 
                         reverseObjectEnumerator] allObjects];
```

I can do it via hardcode but I want to know proper way of handling.

Comment: You have used NSPredicate to filter the array. Now use NSSortDesriptor to sort the filtered array.

Comment: Could you please illustrate ?

Answer (score 0):

To avoid hardcoding you could write a function to reorder the array with any given string as the first string, and utilize that.

For example:

```
void yourFunctionName(string firstString, NSArray &array){
     //Iterate through array
     //Check if you've found a string matching firstString
     //Put it at the front by moving everything else down one
     //Continue to iterate until you've reached the end of the array
}
```

Here it would be best to pass the array by reference (using the &) so that you modify the array itself and not just a copy of the array values (what you get when you don't pass by reference).

Comment: could you please illustrate?

Comment: Sure, you would use a function with parameters to make it so that you can call the function with different options. I tried writing a sample in this comment but the formatting goes away so I'll edit the parent

Comment: Is it objective -c?

Comment: No sorry I program more in c#/c++/java and defaulted to that. However this link is to an explanation of functions in objective-c with examples.

https://www.tutorialspoint.com/objective_c/objective_c_functions.htm